# How to build composer from a source code?

Tags: php, build, composer-php

I have cloned repository from [GitHub](https://github.com/composer/composer). So I am wondering how to build my own composer instance from the source files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It also took me a while to find it, but the installation from source instructions are listed [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md#installation-from-source) in the Composer repository.

Basically you can install Composer from source with Composer, e.g. `composer install`. Very meta! Then you can use the Composer you've installed from source with `path-where-you-cloned-composer/bin/composer`. See the full instructions copied below:

> 1. Run `git clone https://github.com/composer/composer.git`
> 2. Download the [`composer.phar`](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar) executable
> 3. Run Composer to get the dependencies: `cd composer && php ../composer.phar install`
>
> You can run the test suite by executing `vendor/bin/phpunit` when
> inside the composer directory, and run Composer by executing the
> `bin/composer`. To test your modified Composer code against another
> project, run `php /path/to/composer/bin/composer` inside that
> project's directory.

(If you already have Composer installed globally, you don't need to do step 2.)